# AuthenticationException when Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, remoting

We're getting an occasional AuthenticationError thrown when our Client calls methods on the Remoting Server. We can't replicate this issue on demand. In our test environment, we have to restart the server to carry on. In Live, the server seems to be able to carry on after a few seconds. The full text of the exception has been the following:

> "Authentication failed on the remote side (the stream might still be
>   available for additional authentication attempts)."

and

> "No authority could be contacted for authentication."

Generally the first one though.

Here are the sections of the client and server configuration files which I think are relevant.

Server app.config:

```
<system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <!-- Setup the server channel and install the encryption and compression sinks -->
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" name="FastLink" port="8082" secure="true">
          <serverProviders>
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.ClientIPInjectorSinkProvider,PM" />
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.Compression.CompressionServerSinkProvider,SFSiCon" />
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
          </serverProviders>
        </channel>
        <channel ref="tcp" name="RestrictedLink" port="8083" secure="true">
          <serverProviders>
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.ClientIPInjectorSinkProvider,PM" />
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.Compression.CompressionServerSinkProvider,PM" />
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
          </serverProviders>
        </channel>
        <channel ref="tcp" name="WebLink" port="9092" secure="true">
          <serverProviders>
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.ClientIPInjectorSinkProvider,SFSiCon" />
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.Compression.CompressionServerSinkProvider,PM" />
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
          </serverProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
    <customErrors mode="off" />
  </system.runtime.remoting>
```

Client app.config:

```
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <!-- Setup the server channel and install the encryption and compression sinks -->
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" port="0" name="client" secure="true">
          <clientProviders>
            <!-- Install the call context checker sink -->
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.PreRemotingCallClientSinkProvider,PM" />
            <!-- Serialise using the binary formatter  -->
            <formatter ref="binary" />
            <!-- Compress the formatted stream, ready for transmission using the channel -->
            <provider type="PM.Remoting.Compression.CompressionClientSinkProvider,PM" />
          </clientProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
```

Not a lot to go on I know! Any ideas to point me in the right direction will be very grateful!!

Edit:

It's only just started happening after we upgraded from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 in our last release to them.

Comment: I guess you've tried this? http://forums.asp.net/t/1919454.aspx?Authentication+failed+on+the+remote+side+the+stream+might+still+be+available+for+additional+authentication+attempts+

Comment: are any events being logged on either server?

Comment: @Jeb yeah, that is specific to WCF from what I can see.

Comment: @user1666620 we've just noticed that an Error is logged on the Event Viewer on the server: "No Domain Controller is available for domain WORKDCOMAIN due to the following: 
The RPC server is unavailable. . 
Make sure that the computer is connected to the network and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your domain administrator." Unfortunately I can't see the Live system, so we've asked them to check.

Comment: just saw your edit. Can you test on a .Net 2.0 server and see if it works? At least it will rule out that being a factor.

Comment: @user1666620 I'm afraid not. We've since developed additional functionality using 4.0 specific syntax, so it won't run on 2.0. Having heard back form the client, a similar error as above (Domain Controller error) occurs on one of the remoting servers at their end.

Comment: The plot thickens! On a test server, I blocked access to all Domain Controllers. I now get the exception described in the question. This is to be expected. Now, I've also installed an old version of the software running on .Net 2.0 onto another server, and did the same thing to the Domain Controllers. No problem. Using Sysinternals TCPView, you can see that the application running on 4.0 is making calls to the domain to authenticate the user, whilst the version running on 2.0 is not. If I turn "secure" to false in the remoting definition, then it works on both 2.0 and 4.0. Make sense?

Comment: @AledH did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: I believe there is a change in the implementation of the "secure" option on Remoting between 2.0 and 4.0. The additional authentication check which does not happen in 2.0 causes an exception if this fails for any reason. The client is spending some time reviewing their Domain Controller setup to see why these authentication calls are failing. It seems as if the behaviour is correct, but it is unexpected for us. There doesn't seem to be any documentation about a change in this area from Microsoft.